# Open KML in QGis

Tags: qgis, kml

I am very new to QGIS.

I want to open a .kml file in QGIS (downloaded from geoportal.de). If I want to open the downloaded  file directly with QGis an error appears.

I read the tip to first open the .kml in Google Earth, then save the layers separately in Google Earth. Now I can open the layers in QGIS but all I get is a colored box(which seems to lay on the correct coordinates).

The attribute table has also no entries.

Comment: Could you show the error displayed by QGIS when you open your KML file ?

Comment: Did you use the Speichern - Google Earth (KML) option? If you open the KML file with text editor you'll see that all that KML contain are links to WMS server. The file does not have any attributes.

Comment: I don't know why but I had no problems opening the file today...so thanks?!